# Low Level Bluetooth Packet Analysis

Tags: ios, sockets, networking, bluetooth, reverse-engineering

I have a fitness tracker that uses Bluetooth LE, and my iPhone 6+. Unfortunately the app doesn't disclose the raw data coming out of the tracker and zero way to export it, while this data is very interesting to me. I purchased a Bluetooth LE sniffer from Adafruit and used Wireshark to capture packets. While I can open it and analyze the headers with no problem, actual data is somewhat beyond me.

I've looked at posts on the network looking at the packets/frames, but what's the best way to get started analyzing the data? Dumping it into a giant hex editor didn't help (obviously).

Googling the various Info terms was confusing and turned up zero results on the SE network.

Here's a sample of the Wireshark window of packets I assume are data being written while the fitness tracker is tracking movement:

[image]

And more from the packet, randomly chosen:

[image]

Your help in finding some better resources and where to get started on analyzing these packets and their data is appreciated!

Comment: [Bluetooth 4.0: An introduction to Bluetooth Low Energy—Part I](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1278927)

Comment: Thank you - I have read parts 1 and 2 there and while it explains packet size and the like, it provides no real information on actual content or where to go from there. A good overview but not in-depth enough.

Comment: Then maybe explain where you're stuck at.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Is he not explicitly asking how to extract and understand the transmitted data?

Comment: @Trip, if he's read about the protocol, then certainly he has some level of understanding and needs to be specific with his questions.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I thought it was pretty specific: "what's the best way to get started analyzing the data?"

Comment: I also think the data is pretty obvious. So, there's the impasse.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, the helpful community as usual.

Comment: Must be obvious. Zero answers on this post, I have job listings up on two sites willing to pay above market rate for reverse engineering, and yet no responses from any.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of the giant hex editor!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The best way to get started analyzing the data is finding out where the actual data starts and where it ends.**

Disclaimer: I have zero experience with Bluetooth but let's give it a try.

You have two type of captured packets: `Empty PDU` (some form of signaling?) and `ATT`. Searching for data in empty PDUs seems unproductive so let's look at `ATT`.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_protocols#Low_Energy_Attribute_Protocol_.28ATT.29) says:

> **Low Energy Attribute Protocol (ATT)**
>
> It allows a client to read and/or write certain attributes exposed by
>   the server in a non-complex, low-power friendly manner.

That sounds a lot like data.

Quick Google search for *"L2CAP packet format"* reveals multiple formats that start with a 4-byte header: 2 bytes message length + 2 bytes CID (little-endian).

Using `the giant hex editor` we find the respective 4-bytes immediately after the `06 1b` data header. They are `17 00 04 00` which translates to length `23`and CID `0x0004`.

Looking up CID `0x0004` reveals it's indeed the reserved value for ATT.

Time to search the ATT packet format: seems to start with a 1 byte command code.
This is `1d` which means [HANDLE_VALUE_INDICATION](http://openmovement.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Firmware/bleStack/ble%20att.h). The handle is a short (2 bytes) equal to `0x001b` just like in the first image.

So, the 20 bytes after the handle are the value. What it represents it's anyone's guess.

`05 e5 00 83 ff 4a 00 77 77 77 fc 6d fc 37 fc 18 fe 1f 03 43`

Digging up some more reveals that Wireshark should be able to analyze ATT directly (try Decode As?) and that there are tutorials on [learn.adafruit.com](https://learn.adafruit.com/) for the [BLE Sniffer](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-adafruit-ble-bluetooth-low-energy-friend/ble-sniffer) and even an article by a guy who [attempts to reverse-engineer a color changing bulb](https://learn.adafruit.com/reverse-engineering-a-bluetooth-low-energy-light-bulb/sniff-protocol) by analyzing ATT packets.

Comment: Check the [second part](https://learn.adafruit.com/reverse-engineering-a-bluetooth-low-energy-light-bulb/control-with-bluez) of that tutorial. You may be able to get the server characteristic names based on a UUID which will give you an idea what kind of data is in the packets for RE.